# When the Consul server shut down how can i get a message

Tags: consul

if i have three machines running Consul,two Servers and one Client,if one of these machines is shut down,how can i get a error message form Consul,With command line 'consul members' i can get the running info:

[image]

then i want to know whether Consul provides any other methods to tell me which machine is in error state

Comment: please clean up this question and take the time to make the question more clear in regards to what you are trying to ask. also if you have code to support your question, please post relevant code..

Answer (score 0):

If agent shut down you can't get error message via agent end points.

You can get error in log file (that you specified on agent start) at the server where agent was down.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now i can get error info in log file,but i found the log file just noted down error message,how can i set  it notes down warning message